# Setting environment variable python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to set up the environment variable to point to following however it gives me error

```
 os.environ["PATH"]= "C:\APPS\ORACLE\product\12.1.0\Client_64\Instantclient"

I get the error "Invalid character or identifier"
```

I am able to navigate the above path so not sure what is failing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try passing it as a raw string (no need to escape backslashes or anything else then):

```
 os.environ["PATH"]= r"C:\APPS\ORACLE\product\12.1.0\Client_64\Instantclient"
```

Note the prefixed `r` before the string.

Comment: Nice! Better than my approach @Nordle :)

Comment: Thanks! But good eye for spotting where the escaping was needed :)

Comment: Please explain why escape or raw is required here!

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `1` in `12`

```
import os
os.environ["PATH"] = "C:\APPS\ORACLE\product\\12.1.0\Client_64\Instantclient"
print(os.environ['PATH'])
#C:\APPS\ORACLE\product\12.1.0\Client_64\Instantclient
```

Comment: Please explain why!